# If/Then resulting in setting visible=true

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The form is a continuous form and the purpose is to call a list of vendors and then when all the required fields (on a different form) are completed, a calculated field called AllDone, with an IIf statement sets the field to "Yes" for each record (the IIf is done within the table).

Then when the form is loaded, a check-mark should be visible next to the vendor indicating to the user that that vendor is all done. The check-mark is loaded in the table.

The "AllDone" field's result type is Yes/No, format set to Yes/No, and the form's format is set to Yes/No.

It is a simple piece of VBA code and yet I cannot make it work. I have tried several variations; including, adding the .value to Me.AllDone, adding "" around Yes, trying -1, and various combinations. My trial and error has failed, my research stalled; so I turn to SO.

My code:

```
   Private Sub Form_Load()
        If Me.AllDone = Yes Then
            Me.Check.Visible = True
        Else
            Me.Check.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

Thank you!

Comment: Try just using `If Me.AllDone Then` without the equals.

Comment: Thank you for the response. When I run the code that way, all the check-marks are visible even for the no's.

Comment: Following @Roland's advice, then try `Me.AllDone.Value`

Comment: Still showing all the check-marks.

Comment: `Private Sub Form_Load()
        If Me.AllDone.Value Then
            Me.Check.Visible = True
        Else
            Me.Check.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub`

Comment: If the field type is truly set to "Yes/No', then you need to check "= True". Also, where is 'AllDone' - which form?

Comment: Sounds like `Me.check` is on a continuous form and not bound to a field. Unbound controls on continuous forms always have the same value for every datarow.

Comment: @Roland - It is a bound field, I discovered the unbound issue earlier, so I loaded the image as an attachment to each record. Perhaps not the most efficient way but suitable for this application.

Comment: @WayneG.Dunn - if I add Me.AllDone=True nothing happens, with Me.AllDone="True" all the check-marks are not visible.  AllDone is on frmProgramList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't toggle the visibility of controls on a Continuous form for EACH record. You can use Conditional Formatting to disable it, but there is no builtin capability to make it not visible. You might be able to make the background color of the checkbox match the background of the form, which may render it not visible - but I'm not sure if that will work.

Can the user toggle the control on the continuous form? That is, can the user actually edit that value in your continuous form? If not, you could change it to a Textbox, and from there you could modify the background color with Conditional Formatting, based on the value of the field.

To use Conditional Formatting:

Open the form in Design view and select the checkbox, then select Form Design Tools - Format - Conditional Formatting. Add a New Rule:

Field Value Is Equal False (or True, depending on what you want to do)

Now set the Backcolor to the same as the detail section of your continuous form. When Access encounters that rule, it will examine the value of that field and will set the Backcolor accordingly.

Comment: thanks! that did work. I set the expression for the Conditional Format to an Iff statement. If the fields have been completed the textbox on the form turns green (for go).